# Error with "nokuntusp" package when trying to install packages

Tags: package-management

During any install from Ubuntu Sofware Centre or using the command line, I am getting the following error

```
E: The package nokuntusp needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive 
for it.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: where did you get that package from?

Comment: You need to tell us what you did when you were trying to install "nokuntusp", as that seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

it is simple...

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq nokuntusp
```

run above command in terminal.
It will not asks u to "package nokuntusp needs to be reinstalled".

And synaptic package manager will starts to work.